# C++ To-Do List repeats inputs. How to avoid that?

Tags: c++, string, input, counter, cin

> I have the following code, and I'm trying to create a very simple (not so simple) to-do list.  The desired outcome is as follows:
>
> 1) Wake up
>     2) Thank God I'm alive.

...C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string list_entry;
    cout << "What would you like to add to your to-do list?" << endl;
    int count = 1;
    while (true) {
        getline(cin,list_entry) 
        cout << count << ")" << list_entry << endl;
        count++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

...C++

...output

I'm getting the following output, which is NOT the desired outcome:

```
What would you like to add to your to-do list?
Wake up
1)Wake up
Thank God I'm alive
2)Thank God I'm alive
Make the bed
3)Make the bed
```

...output

> The desired outcome is as follows:
>
> What would you like to add to your to-do list?
>      1) Wake up
>      2) Thank God I'm Alive
>      3) Make the bed
>      etc.

Comment: Get rid of `cin.ignore();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Simple ToDo List C++.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

//#include "stdafx.h"   edited out
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>


using namespace std;

//function prototypes required in C++
int printvalues(string str1);



int main()
{
    string list_entry = "";

    std::cout << "What would you like to add to your to-do list?" << std::endl;

// while(true) is an infinite loop.  It exits when exit is sent to
// printvalues and it evaluates to the exit(0);  which means exit with an 
// error code of 0.  Other way to exit a loop is with the break keyword.

    while (true) {
        getline(std::cin, list_entry);
        if (list_entry != "print") { printvalues(list_entry); }
        if (list_entry == "print") { printvalues("print"); }

    }
    // return required by most compilers is an int.  main is an int in this 
    // program so return returns an int value.
    return 0;
};

// function "definition" for the function we put at the top.  defines the 
// body of the function
int printvalues(string str1) {
    // static variables in C++ will retain their set values next time this 
    // function is called withe printvalues(list_entry) or 
    // printvalues("print") or printvalues("exit")
    static int i = 0;
    static string all[30];

    // if list_entry is not != the word print, add the value at index i and 
    // increment i using i++;
    if (str1 != "print") { all[i] = str1; i++ }

    //iterator i2
    int i2;

    // if we typed print inside the while (true) loop in main then print all 
    // the values in a for loop starting at all[i2].
    if (str1 == "print") {
        for (i2 = 0; i2 < i; i2++) {
            //print i2 + 1 makes the value start at 1 so we don't print out 
            // 0) Make the bed , we print out 1)
            cout << i2 + 1 << ")" << all[i2] << endl;
        }
    }
    // if exit was typed then the values are stored but it doesnt matter 
    // because they aren't printed and the program exits with a error code 
    // of 0 which is success.
    if (str1 == "exit") { exit(0); }
    return 0;
}
```

I ran this exact code in visual studio in a new project and it worked.. type each item and hit enter.. when you're done  type print on a new line and hit enter and it will print the values.

Comment: J.A.R., I know this is asking a lot, but could you include more comments to explain what you're doing with the code.

Comment: static string all[30] is the array of strings we store the strings in.  everything else you should recognize. for loop, if block, function prototype at the top (which are required in C++), exit(0) exits the program, return is required by most compilers, static, i explained holds the values across multiple function calls so static i, and static all[30].  comparison operator not equal != ... comparison operator equal ==.  This was kind of an interesting idea because you can keep entering and printing.  until you type exit.

Comment: you should experiment with arrays of type string.  there are some containers that are new to me.  list and map.  are like ArrayList in VB and HashTable in VB.  There is also one called vector.  I have never worked with any of them, excet in Visual Basic.

Comment: Thank you Jason.  I appreciate the clarification and the advice.  I'll run with it.  Thanks again!  By the way, I got it to work this time.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

> b) the next available input character is delim, as tested by Traits::eq(c, delim), in which case the delimiter character is extracted from input, but is not appended to str.

There is no need call ignore() to skip '\n' with std::getline().

Answer (score -2):

```
int printvalues(string);

main() {
  while (true) {
    getline(cin, list_entry); //cin.ignore();
    if (list_entry != "print") {
      printvalues(list_entry);
    }
    if (list_entry == "print") {
      printvalues("print");
    }
  }
}

int printvalues(string str1) {
  static int i = 0;
  static string all[3];
  all[i] = str1;
  i++;
  int i2;
  if (str1 == "print") {
    for (i2 = 0; i2 <= i; i2++) {
      cout << i2 << ")" << all[i2] << endl;
    }
    exit(0);
  }
}
```

call this function when you read in any string with printvalues(list_entry), when you are done call this function with printvalues("print") and it will print all the values.

Comment: static variables inside functions hold their values during all calls to that function.  If you set i = 1, next time you call the function it will be 1.  So, make a static array of all[3] and add the list_entry strings into it in the function.

Comment: that's ok.  what error are you getting.  i changed the code.  all[i] << endl, shold be all[i2] << endl;